# How to emulate "window" object in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

When running in a browser, everything attached to the "window" object will automatically become global object. How can I create an object similar to that in Nodejs?

```
mySpecialObject.foo = 9;
var f = function() { console.log(foo); };
f();  // This should print "9" to console
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the predefined object `global` for that purpose. If you define `foo` as a property of the `global` object, it will be available in all modules used after that. 
For example, in *app.js*:

```
var http = require('http');
var foo = require('./foo');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  //Define the variable in global scope.
  global.foobar = 9;
  foo.bar();    
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

And in *foo.js*:

```
exports.bar = function() {
  console.log(foobar);
}
```

Make sure you don't use the `var` keyword as the `global` object is already defined.

For documentation, check out http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global.

Comment: But be careful, unlike browser javascript, global objects aren't truly global in the sense of the word. They are still local to a module, that is a javascript file. In other words, anything attached to global object of a file won't be available in another file, you will have to attach it to special `module.exports` object. For more info check out how nodejs require works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the notice. I've come to this simple solution: var mySpecialObject = global. In browser (at global scope): mySpecialObject = this.

Answer (score 3):

you can attach global stuff to `process` instead of `window`

Comment: I mean I want to create a special object similar to "window". Attaching "foo" to it will make "foo" global.

Answer (score 3):

You can now use [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) instead of both `global` and `window` regardless of the environment. Every recent browser and Node 12+ supports it. It’s part of ES2020

```js
// BEFORE
global.foo = 9;     // ⚠️ Node only
window.foo = 9;     // ⚠️ Browser only, no service workers

// AFTER
globalThis.foo = 9; // ✅ Everywhere!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GLOBAL object.

```
fruit = 'banana';
console.log(GLOBAL.fruit); // prints 'banana'

var car = 'volks';
console.log(GLOBAL.car); // prints undefined
```

Comment: Shouldn't `GLOBAL` be lowercase?

Comment: @Infigon the `GLOBAL` object was available in Node versions up until v0.12.0 (when this answer was posted). It is now deprecated and it's been replaced with `global` (in lowercase).

Answer (score 0):

If you were to compare the Web Console to Node running in terminal (both Javascript) :

`window` <-> `global` (Note: GLOBAL is deprecated)

in Web Console : `window.wgSiteName` (random to show functionality)

in Node (Terminal): `global.url`

`document` <-> `process` (Note: program process running right now)

in Web Console : `document.title`

in Node (Terminal): `process.title`

Answer (score -1):

I've come to this simple solution:

```
var mySpecialObject = global;
```

In normal browser:

```
var mySpecialObject = this;  // Run this at global scope
```