# Using materialize-css in express/react SSR app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, materialize, server-side-rendering

I have an express server that uses Server Side Rendering (SSR) to render a react app.

I want to use the `materialize-css` package together with my react app.

I have imported the `materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css` and `materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min` into my App.js.

Before I used express to render my app server side it worked fine, styling and modals from materialize was loaded correctly.

Now when I try to render my app using express, I get following error:

```
[0] ReferenceError: window is not defined
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Sites/task_keeper/node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js:6:1135)
[0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
[0]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
[0]     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
[0]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
[0]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
[0]     at eval (webpack:///external_%22materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min%22?:1:18)
```

This is my render middleware:

```
const renderMiddleware = () => (req, res) => {
  let html = req.html;
  const htmlContent = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);
  const htmlReplacements = {
    HTML_CONTENT: htmlContent,
  };

  Object.keys(htmlReplacements).forEach(key => {
    const value = htmlReplacements[key];
    html = html.replace(
      new RegExp('__' + escapeStringRegexp(key) + '__', 'g'),
      value
    );
  });

  res.send(html);
};
```

And then I use hydrate in `index.js`,

```
ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));.
```

What is the correct way to use `materialize-css` in a setup like this?

Comment: window should be the parent object of document, server-sided it's not existing though as it's related to the browers and could be a virtual container. If you work with (I)frames you can probably remark similar problems.

Comment: @David Thank you for the reply. I know that window and document is not available server side, so I'm thinking about loading the js after the app has been rendered server side. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: It doesn't change much concerning `window` and `document` but that would probably enable you to render without errors first. So yes, sounds like a reasonable and good solution.

Comment: another question is if you can emulate window and document server sided, but if it's not required that would be better probably

Comment: That would be cool.

Comment: With drupal you're using PHP, so you could have a look how the PHP-DOM library is  treating `window` and `document` - if existing at all

Comment: I found this post which seems interesting, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126003/node-js-document-is-not-defined.

Comment: I'm a bit astonished that `document` never exists server sided but the DOM-Library has one: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php but it seems it's just related to a text-document in HTML or XML.

Comment: Have a look here, in node.js you could emulate it withe help of the global keyword: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14452632/1019850

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by loading the script with a CDN, like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

This way the script is injected into the `window` variable, so you can use `window.M.AutoInit()`, for instance.

So in the component where you use the modals, autoinit them in a useEffect callback:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.M.AutoInit();
}, []);
```

Comment: `<script src="...">` is not working in that kind server sided.

Comment: Yes it does if i include it in my app.html.

Comment: Ahh ok, I never considered it that way ;-)